# Is a returned data in PHP always a string?

Tags: php, arrays, string, curl

I'm getting data with the PHP function below - is the returned data always a string or can it be an array too?

```
function getData($xPostURL,$xToken,$xTokenSecret,$xAccount)
{ 
    $datatopost = array (
        "token" =>  $xToken,
        "tokenSecret" => $xTokenSecret,
        "account" => $xAccount,
    );

    $ch = curl_init ($xPostURL);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datatopost);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $returnedData = curl_exec ($ch);

    echo $returnedData;
}

getData("http://www.example.com/foo.php","","","");
```

Below is how the `foo.php` data gets returned, via print_r():

```
print_r($myArray);
```

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => world
    [2] => xyz
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data returned by curl will always be a string. HTTP works exclusively with text, it cannot transport anything else. curl does not interpret this text to turn it into anything else.

Comment: OK, thank you. How can I turn the String back into an Array? I tried `$getNames =  unserialize($getNames);` but that didn't work. Are there alternatives?

Comment: To use unserialize() to receive the data, you'd need to use serialize() instead of print_r() when sending the data. Then it should work as you expect.

Comment: @Tom Use a proper *serialization format*. `serialize()` is one option, JSON, XML are others.

Comment: I'm trying to merge the returned array with another one but I'm receiving this error: `Argument #1 is not an array`. What could be the reason that `serialize()` is not working?

Comment: @Tom ... and how exactly are you employing `serialize`?

Comment: @deceze This is the code that returns that error: `$dataFoo = unserialize($dataFoo);
$dataBar = unserialize($dataBar);

$merged = array_merge($dataFoo,$dataBar);
print_r($merged);`

Answer (score 1):

If `foo.php` produces its output by calling `print_r()` then that is what the other script (the one that uses `curl`) gets. I.e. a string that looks like the output of `print_r()`.

If you want `foo.php` return an array then you need to change `foo.php` to represent this array as string and output that string then, in the client code parse the string representation of the array to reconstruct the array in memory.

There are many ways in PHP to produce a string representation of a data structure. JSON is the best (in my opinion), XML can also be used, the internal PHP serialization also works (it is the only one that can store and recreate objects that embed recursive references), `var_export()` can also do it.

A quick list:

- **JSON**: use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the data in `foo.php`; use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to analyze the string (returned by `curl_exec()`) and re-create the data structure at the other end; pass `TRUE` as the second argument to `json_decode()` to get an array, otherwise it will produce a PHP [object](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php).

  Advantages `[+]` and disadvantages `[-]`:

  - `[+]` it is standard representation, very-well understood by other programming languages (directly by the language or by some of its libraries);
  - `[+]` it produces the shortest possible text representation;
  - `[+]` the encoding and decoding are very easy: both need a single call to the correct function;
  - `[+]` this is also the fastest method, both on encoding and decoding;
- **XML**: use the [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) classes and functions to create the `XML` object then iteratively add the data to it. Call method [`SimpleXMLElement::asXML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) to create the text representation of the `XML` and output it. Then use [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or the myriad of methods of class [`SimpleXML`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to extract the data from it.

  - `[+]` the XML format is standardized, very popular and supported by many other programming languages;
  - `[+]` it can be used to transfer large data structures;
  - `[+]` the parsing can be done incrementally and only the needed data extracted; there is no need to recreate the entire structure in the memory;
  - `[-]` both encoding and decoding require a lot of code;
  - `[-]` the text representation is big; for data structures containing small strings it is usually about 2 times bigger than the equivalent `JSON`;
  - `[-]` the speed of the code is also bad, both on encoding and decoding (it's the worst method presented here);
- PHP **serialization**: use PHP function [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) to represent the data structure as string; use function [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) to parse the string and recreate the PHP data structures.

  - `[+]` the length of the text representation is not very big; it is slightly bigger than `JSON` but not very much;
  - `[+]` it can handle (both encode and decode) data structures that contain cyclic references (the other methods cannot do that);
  - `[+]` it can handle objects (`OOP`); on the reconstruction it needs to know the definition of the classes used in the text or a way to load them;
  - `[+]` the speed on both encoding and decoding is slightly worse than the one of `json_encode()`/`json_decode()` but not significant;
  - `[-]` it is an internal representation of PHP. No other language understands it off the shelf; one needs to write a parser to analyze the text representation and restore the data structures (but this is an easy job, the format is simple).
- **http_build_query()**: this can be used only for arrays that contain scalar values. Use function [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to produce the string representation of the input data (an array). Use function [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the string and recreate the original array.

  - `[+]` the string produced by `http_build_query()` is an URL-encoded query string which is a standard way of passing data between web pages. It can be easily decoded in the languages used for web development and also in other languages as well;
  - `[+]` it produces the shortest text representation because it does not encode the types of the values...
  - `[-]` ... but this forces the values in the recreated array to be strings; there is no way to restore the original types (because they are lost on encoding);
- **var_export()**: the PHP function [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) produces the PHP code that can be used to generate the data structure in memory; reconstruction of the data structure can be done by running that code.

  `[+]` the output is correct PHP code; it can be easily inspected and modified by humans;
  `[+]` the data restoring is probably the fastest of all methods presented here but the risks (see below) do not match the gain (which is irrelevant, anyway);
  `[-]` because reconstruction is done by running or evaluating PHP code, it could do anything on behalf of the code that runs it;
  `[-]` running code downloaded from another server is a very severe security issue; even if you control the other server, a malicious hacker could use different techniques to divert your request to a server they control or append some extra code to the code generated by the other server; the code produced by the hacker will execute on your server and since that very moment your server is not yours any more;
  **never** run automatically code downloaded from another server!

#### Conclusion

There are many ways to transfer data structures from one script that runs on a server to another script that runs on another server. The best of all (in my opinion) is `JSON` followed by `XML`. They have the advantage of being portable and well-supported by other languages as well. `JSON` is fast, small and easy to use. `XML` is more difficult to use but this is because it is much flexible and can be processed in many ways.

PHP serialization is also a good alternative to `JSON` if you don't need to exchange data with systems that don't run PHP and `JSON` cannot help you.

The other options are described here only for educational purposes.

**Never** run or evaluate automatically code downloaded from other websites.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! I managed to fix my data problem based on that!